# Django reverse foreignkey relationship failing

Tags: django, django-models

I have set up two models where one has a foreign key relationship to the other. Since I have multiple databases I also set up a routers.py file as both databases live in the same application. I have been reading and following the documenation found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) and as far as I can tell I am following the documentation to the letter.

**models.py**

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'customers'
        app_label = 'db1'

class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, models.CASCADE)
    active = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        app_label = 'db1'
```

**routers.py**

```
class BackendRouter(object):

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'db1':
            return 'default'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'db2':
            return 'db2'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'db1':
            return 'default'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'db2':
            return 'db2'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'db1' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'db1':
           return True
        elif obj1._meta.app_label == 'db2' or \
            obj2._meta.app_label == 'db2':
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'db1':
            return db == 'default'
        elif app_label == 'db2':
            return db == 'db2'
        return None
```

Ignore for a second that I have a `users` table without deriving from `AbstractBaseUser`, when I run the following query:

`Customers.objects.filter(users__username__contains='sl')`

I get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'users' into
>   field. Choices are: active, customer_id, name

Per the example in the documentation:

`Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')`

This should work. What am I missing here?

---

As a point of reference I have already tried the following as well:

`Customers.objects.filter(users_set__username__contains=‘sl’)`

As well as setting `related_name='users'` on the `customers` ForeignKey.

Comment: You know you don't have a `username` field in your `Users` class, right?

Comment: @ChristianTernus sorry about that, must of deleted it when I deleted the rest of the cruft. Rest assured it is there now in the example and definitely there in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs, it seems I should be able to filter the way I have in my question and not run into an issue. However I am not sure if I can actually filter on more than a single object when doing "reverse" relations. I did achieve what I wanted with the following solution:

```
user = Users.objects.filter(username='someuser').only('customer_id')
customer = Customers.objects.filter(customer_id__in=user)
```

I am sure there is a more efficient way though. Like such:

```
Users.objects.filter(username='someuser').values_list('customer__name', flat=True)[0]
```

I just figured it would be better if I could get what I need via something like:

```
Customers.objects.filter(users__username='someuser').values_list('name', flat=True)[0]
```

---

It actually appears that this was caused by both of my models living in the same application. Once I split them out into there own seperate apps, reverse relationships began to work.